# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/loginDB & java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, sqlexception, tomcat9

I am having a problem where the Eclipse IDE does not recognize the jdbc driver in the .jar file. I have already tried putting it in the build path from WEB-INF/Lib and also the build folder. I have already added the Class.forname in my project to register the driver.

This is my url to my database in mysql: "jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/loginDB".
I am using Tomcat v9.0 server.
I'm using 5.1.49 driver version for the .jar file.

The following link will bring you to my github, where my code is for my project.

https://github.com/shari002/files/tree/master/MyResgistrationProjects

[This shows how I'm registering for driver to work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EhOf.png)

Comment: Can you share the project code on github? That one screenshot is of no help.

Comment: Just edited. My whole project should be viewable.

Link: https://github.com/shari002/files/tree/master/MyResgistrationProjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your connection string.

> **jbdc**:mysql://localhost:3306/loginDB

It should be ***jdbc***.